# How to send a customer email from Stripe CLI?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Checkout. Once the user has paid, I need to save his payment infos in my database. To this purpose, I use Stripe's webhook.

Since I can't use webhook in test mode, I had to install Stripe CLI. The issue is that I can't send a customer email in my payload. Ergo, I can't save the user payment info in my database during development.

The cli command I use is: `stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded`

The server route called by the webhook looks like this:

```js
const buy = async (req: Request, res: IResponse): Promise<IResponse> => {
  try {
    const signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
    const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      req.rawBody,
      signature,
     process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    );
    if (event.type === "payment_intent.succeeded") {
      const { id, amount_paid, customer_email } = event.data.object as Invoice;
      const serialNumber = await PaymentControler.generateUniqueSerialNumber();
      await PaymentControler.updateUserMembership(
        customer_email,
        id,
        amount_paid,
        serialNumber
      );
      return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    res.status(500).send("Error processing payment");
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send("Error processing payment");
  }
};
```

Here is how the client sends the request to Stripe Checkout:

```js
  const checkoutOptions: RedirectToCheckoutOptions = {
    lineItems: [
      {
        price: process.env.STRIPE_APP_PRICE,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    successUrl: `${location}?success=true&invoiceID={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancelUrl: `${location}?success=false`,
    submitType: "pay",
    customerEmail: user?.email,
  };
```

How to send a customer email from Stripe CLI?

Also, could you please confirm to me that I'm correctly accessing the properties: `id`, `amount_paid`, and `customer_email` in the `event.data.object` (they don't exist right now, so I want to make sure it'll be alright in production)?

Answer (score 1):

The `invoice.payment_succeeded` event doesn't really have anything to do with Checkout as such. The event you'd likely want to trigger is `checkout.session.completed` and use `--add` flag to customize the customer email parameter

For example something like;
`stripe trigger checkout.session.completed --add checkout_session:customer_email="test@email.com"`

That should allow you to test your code and make sure it is working as intended.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I receive the error: `Trigger failed: Request failed, status=400, body={"error": {"message": "An error has occurred confirming the Checkout Session.","request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/idoflog","type": "invalid_request_error"}}` My server is never called, so the error comes from the request. Without the --add flag, it works. But I don't have the email.

Answer (score 0):

The flag won't take an email as a parameter. However, you can go into your stripe dashboard and see the `customerId` for the email you want to use. Copy that id and pass it into your flag like this:

`stripe trigger checkout.session.completed --add checkout_session:customer="customerId"`

This will successfully trigger the event.